Timer based Azure Function stopped indexing all of a sudden
I have an Azure Function running in Azure.
It is timer triggered.
It worked as it should up until a week ago. I haven't redeployed any code or anything. It just stopped working all of a sudden.
Now i get this error:
The 'MyTimerFunction' function is in error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'MyTimerFunction'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter '$return' to type IActionResult&. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

My code (updated with full code on request) is listed below.
As I wrote earlier. This code has been running every night until about a week ago with nor problems. So The problems did come from nowhere.
public static class MyFunction
{
    // Static HttpClient instance
    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = InitializeHttpClient(); //Used later in code to call external API

    // Method to initialize HttpClient with configurable timeout
    private static HttpClient InitializeHttpClient()
    {
        // Get the timeout value from the environment variable, default to 100 seconds if not set
        string timeoutEnvVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_CLIENT_TIMEOUT");
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100); // Default value

        // Try parsing the environment variable to set a custom timeout
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(timeoutEnvVar) && int.TryParse(timeoutEnvVar, out int timeoutSeconds))
        {
            timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds);
        }

        // Initialize HttpClient with the parsed or default timeout
        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            Timeout = timeout
        };

        return client;
    }

    [FunctionName("MyTimerFunction")]
    public static async Task RunTimer([TimerTrigger("%TimerSchedule%")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log) //TimerSchedule set to 0 0 0 * * * in environment variable
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function started at: {DateTime.Now}");

        await RunWork(log); //private method that calls the external API with the httpClient
    }

    private static async Task<OkObjectResult> RunWork(ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            var nr = await ImportAndPost(log);
            return new OkObjectResult($"Function executed successfully. Count: {nr}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            return new OkObjectResult($"Function encountered an error!");
        }
    }

    private static async Task<int> ImportAndPost(ILogger log)
    {
        var username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ck");
        var password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("cs");
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

        var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}");
        var base64Credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(credentials);

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Credentials);

        var url = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("rp_url");
        var apiUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("api_url")?.TrimEnd('/');
        
        int pageSize = int.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("page_size") ?? "10");
        int maxPages =     int.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("max_pages") ?? "0");
       
        int importId = -1;
        var allModels = new List<TemporaryModel>();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        int page = 1;
        bool morePages = true;

        while (morePages && (maxPages == 0 || page <= maxPages))
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Fetching page {page}...");
            var paginatedUrl = $"{rpUrl}?page={page}&per_page={pageSize}";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(paginatedUrl);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            if (page == 1)
            {
                importId = await StartAPIImport(log);
            }

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var tempModels = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TemporaryModel>>(content, options);
            allModels.AddRange(tempModels);
            var models = MapToRealModels(tempModels, log);

            log.LogInformation($"Posting page {page} to the API");
            var postTask = Task.Run(() => PostModelsToApi(importId, models, log));
            tasks.Add(postTask);

            if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("X-WP-TotalPages", out var totalPagesValues))
            {
                int totalPages = int.Parse(totalPagesValues.First());

                if (page >= totalPages)
                {
                    morePages = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                morePages = false;
            }

            page++;
        }
        log.LogInformation($"Nr of pages: {page - 1}");

        log.LogInformation($"Waiting for all API post tasks to     finish...");
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        log.LogInformation($"All API posts tasks finished.");
        await EndAPIImport(importId, log);
        return allModels.Count;
    }

    private static async Task<int> StartAPIImport(ILogger log)
    {
        var jsonRequest = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
        {
            Name = "Test"
        });

        var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var apiUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("api_url")?.TrimEnd('/');
        var apiEndpoint = $"{apiUrl}/start-import";

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(apiEndpoint, content);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception($"API-call failed with status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }

        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var importId = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int>(responseContent);

        log.LogInformation($"Import Id {importId} start was successful.");

        return importId;
    }

    private static async Task EndAPIImport(int importId, ILogger log)
    {
        var apiUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("api_url")?.TrimEnd('/');
        var apiEndpoint = $"{apiUrl}/end-import/{importId}";

        try
        {
            var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(apiEndpoint, null);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                log.LogError($"EndImport API call for Import Id {importId} failed with status code: {response.StatusCode}");
                throw new Exception($"EndImport API call failed with status code: {response.StatusCode}");
            }

            log.LogInformation($"EndImport API for Import Id {importId} call was successful.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError($"An error occurred during EndImport API call for Import Id {importId}: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static async Task PostModelsToApi(int importId, List<Model> models, ILogger log)
    {
        var jsonRequest = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new
        {
            ImportId = importId,
            Name = "Test",
            Models = models
        });

        var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var apiUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("api_url")?.TrimEnd('/');
        var apiEndpoint = $"{apiUrl}/import-models";

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(apiEndpoint, content);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new Exception($"API-call failed with status code: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
    }

    private static List<Model> MapToRealModels(List<TemporaryModel> tempModels, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            var models = new List<Model>();

            foreach (var tempModel in tempModels)
            {   
                var newModel = new Model();
                newModel.Externalid = tempModel.Id.ToString();
                newModel.DisplayName = tempModel.Name;
                models.Add(newModel);
            }
            return models;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            return new List<Model>();
        }
    }
}

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Can you share your complete code in the question?

@DasariKamali: I have edited the original post with the complete code. Thank you!

EDIT: For those of you who have run into this issue as of late, and have been forced to upgrade to GitHub Actions actions/upload-artifact@v4 (or v3) in your pipeline, you need to add:
include-hidden-files: true in your upload step. Example:
- name: Upload AzureFunctions Artifact
              uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
              with:
                name: azurefunctions
                path: ./build/azurefunctions
                include-hidden-files: true

Versions 3 and 4 of actions/upload-artifact ignore hidden files by default. In order for deployments to Azure Functions to work, the hidden .azurefunctions folder is required.
Original Answer:
The error seems to be telling you that your TimerTrigger function cannot return an IActionResult.
Looking at your code, your RunWork method returns an OkObjectResult and Functions is taking that as your return value.
You might want to start by making your RunTimer method's second line to:
_ = await RunWork(log);

You could leave it at that, or, possibly, add:
return Task.CompletedTask();

to the end of the method.
As far as I can tell, when you simply await RunWork(log) Azure Functions will use the returned Task<OkObjectResult> (read by Functions as Task<IActionResult>) as the return value of the function, thus throwing the error.
So, to avoid this, you can discard the return value of await RunWork(log) explicitly, and then make sure you return a valid Task type for the TimerTrigger to understand that execution has completed.

Thank you! I made this change:
_ = await RunWork(log);
However, that didn't work. I still receive the same error.

@supremo I actually just ran into a similar-ish issue with our last deployment to our Azure Functions. Our functions are running on a Linux instance of Azure Functions, which has, for some unknown reason, broken completely. Rolling back to our original deployment version didn't fix it either. It seems like there is some kind of bug in the Azure Functions Linux system that is randomly causing issues with code that has been running for months without issue. Can you try deploying this to a Windows instance just to check if that works?
